# ubuntu kernel git for xenial gives wrong source version

Tags: kernel, 16.04, git, source

I'm trying to pull kernel sources from this location:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/

And I'm expecting to see 4.4.0-21/22 related sources.

What I'm getting is 4.4.8 version code.  Is something configured wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the wrong version? Do you build a kernel from there? How do you build it?

Comment: I'm first pulling sources directly from the Ubuntu git repository. So my build only uses what is downloaded. The build results show that a kernel with version 4.4.8 is produced. Plus the Makefile shows an internal version of 4.4.8. The Git repository indicates the 4.4.0 sources are stored. A clear difference that I see.

Answer (score 0):

You probably build the kernel not a Debian way. This way you are getting a mainline kernel version.

You need to build the kernel by

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

This way you will get Ubuntu versions.

Comment: I'm first pulling sources directly from the Ubuntu git repository. So my build only uses what is downloaded. The build results show that a kernel with version 4.4.8 is produced. Plus the Makefile shows an internal version of 4.4.8. The Git repository indicates the 4.4.0 sources are stored. A clear difference that I see.

Comment: If you build using `debian/rules`, you will get the correct Ubuntu version.